# How to set useState initial value of object which is already in my fake data?

Tags: reactjs, object, undefined, use-state

I was declared a state named:

```
const [quantity,setQuantity] = useState(products.qty)
```

I need `products.qty` will be my initial state value but it showed undefined.

Below I attached my fake data object:

```js
products =[{
      "user":"tareque@gmail.com",
      "name": "Mathis England",
       "img":   "https://i.ibb.co/C8JtD0Z/bicycle-1.png",
       "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur",
       "price": 300,
       "qty": 20,
       "supplier": "Velocy"
     
}
]
```

Comment: `products` is an array. Try `useState(products[0].qty)`

Comment: why don't you set the qty by default to 20 as initial state since it's fixed? ```useState(20)```

Comment: Not work, When I checked products.qty  in console its showed value, But it cant take in useState(product.qty)

Comment: Amr- i have more data . thats why i need dynamic value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working, you can see the value in the console and in h1

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { products } from "./products";

export default function App() {
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(products[0].qty);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("qty = ", quantity);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{quantity}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

your data source file `products.js`

```
export const products = [
  {
    user: "tareque@gmail.com",
    name: "Mathis England",
    img: "https://i.ibb.co/C8JtD0Z/bicycle-1.png",
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur",
    price: 300,
    qty: 20,
    supplier: "Velocy"
  }
];
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-violet-bfg2h8?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

I think this should answer your question for mocking up a static data.
as per your example, the array has only one object.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const products = [
  {
    user: "tareque@gmail.com",
    name: "Mathis England",
    img: "https://i.ibb.co/C8JtD0Z/bicycle-1.png",
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur",
    price: 300,
    qty: 20,
    supplier: "Velocy",
  },
];
const Demo = () => {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(products[0].qty);

  return <h1>{quantity}</h1>;
};

export default Demo;
```

otherwise, if you would like to set the state to a dynamic data, then you should use [useEffect](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook as side effect to set the state after the component is mounted.